# call Web Service from C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I've a simple Web Service `getAD.asmx` that I use to retrieve data from active directory. I need to execute WS as a specific user, and be sure that only corporate user could consume it, so I'm using Windows authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation.

I tried to add a local simple web form to test my service, and it seems to work correctly

```
getAD myWS = new getAD();
string testResult = myWS.test(); // testResult execute correctly
```

Now I'm trying to call the same service from another C# application, so I added a Web Reference and did the same call, but I get a 401 error (Unauthorized) with any user.

```
rbasws01.getAD myWS = new rbasws01.getAD();
string testResult = myWS.test(); // error 401, not authorized
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT: this is the code of my WebService

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://myUri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class getAD : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public string test() {
        return "Test positive";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `http://example.com/webservice/getAD` from within somewhere within `http://example.com`?

Comment: If I use a browser and type `http://myServer/webservice/getAD.asmx` I can see existing methods

Comment: Yes, but have you deployed this on a server with IIS which http://example.com/ points to?

Comment: I'm using this server only inside my corporate network, so I'll just use `http://myServer/`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `localhost:[some-port-number]` binding on your IIS and pointing your request of the webservice to that.

So instead of calling `http://myUri.org/ws/something`, call `http://localhost:1234/ws/something` from within your application.

IIS can be a bit funny sometimes about talking to itself - <strike>I read this is to prevent some kind of attacks, but never was able to find the link again!</strike> Thanks to @LeeHarrison, this is called Loopback Checking.

Another way of getting round this issue is to disable Loopback Checking as described in [this KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861).

Comment: You are correct, it is called loopback prevention. Older version of IIS could be spoofed into thinking an attacker was someone on the local machine, and grant permissions that would have otherwise been more difficult to obtain. This can be disabled by a few registry tweaks. Google "disable loopback IIS" if your interested.

Comment: @LeeHarrison Thanks! I could never figure out what to google so cheers.

Comment: @dav_i it didn't help to solve my problem but it's interesting